# Data Cols in Google Sheets Query Formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

What I'm trying to do is to make a query formula returning year sales by week number filtered by store.

Example sheet: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MUrxE54nBKnsBemOAAkjse6wRI9dO3i4EktHWg5k8_A/edit?usp=sharing)

It's easy to do with formula like this one: `=Query(query(A:D,"Select A,Sum(D) where A is not null group by A Pivot B",1),"Select * offset 1",0)`

But I also need to filter results based on specific store (Col C)

It's also not hard:
`=Query(query(A:D,"Select A,Sum(D) where C = 'First' AND A is not null group by A Pivot B",1),"Select * offset 1",0)`

But in this case any week with 0 sales and store equals to 'Second' will be missed.

I would like to show all weeks (Col A) presented in the data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({A:B, IF(C:C<>"First", {"First", 0}, C:D)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col4) 
  where Col3 = 'First' 
    and Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2"), "offset 1", 0))
```